# Trying to create a dynamic Depends On Array for an Azure ARM Template

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a dynamic DependOn Property in the ARM template configuration like this

```
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
  "dependsOn": [],
```

I do have scenarios where the dependOn is needed. So I'm creating a variable that dynamically adds data to an array if a resource requires that type of data as a dependency.

For example, my virtual machine may depend on an availability set if I set a parameter to include an availability set as true in the parameter section.

Till now, the only way to do this is calling dynamic variables (arrays) based on true/false answers like this:

variables(concat('Dependon_AS_',parameters('IncludeAS'))

Are there better ways to handle this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understoof the problem you dont need dynamic dependsOn. dependsOn honours conditions, so if the element is skipped due to `condition: false`, there will be no error.

Comment: I already applied the condition on the availability set resource. If its condition is set to false, then it wont be deployed, but the VM resource still has the dependOn section. If i try to deploy the template, I'll get an error for pointing to a deployment that hasn't occurred.

Comment: no, thats not how it Works. `dependsOn` honors conditions and doesnt cause errors if conditions skip resources. here's an [example](https://github.com/rjmax/ArmExamples/blob/master/if.AvailabilitySet.json)

Comment: @4c74356b41 this does not work. if you have a dependsOn in a resource, but one of the elements in the dependsOn array will not be created due to another condition, the creation of the initial resource will fail because it will not find that resource which it is dependant to. I tried to workaround this, by creating array variables and using if condition in the dependsOn array but I am getting this: `Evaluation result of language expression <if condition> is type 'Array', expected type is 'String'`

Comment: no thats not true: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/define-resource-dependency#dependson. I mean, if your resource really depends on a resource not created - its your mistake. you cant do that. but that is obvious